# Is it possible to stop animated object when it encounters a div?

Tags: javascript, animation

I managed to cobble together this simple animated-object game. I have a var named guy and in my html I have a div called #obstacle.

Is it possible to do something like if "guy" encounters "obstacle" stop the function so that "guy" can't pass through it? Or is that too simplified? I'm thinking something along the lines of if guy's x,y equal the x,y of #obstacle, don't allow keydown. Sorry if I'm oversimplifying this.

```
var guy = document.getElementById("guy"); 
var container = document.getElementById("container"); 
var guyLeft = 0; 
var y = 0;  
function anim(e) { 
if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
    guyLeft += 10; guy.style.left = guyLeft + "px"; 
        } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        guyLeft -= 10; guy.style.left = guyLeft + "px"; 
        } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        y += 10; guy.style.top = y + "px"; 
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        y -= 10; guy.style.top = y + "px"; 
        } else if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        y -= 134; guy.style.top = y + "px"; 
        x += 134; guy.style.right = x + "px"; 
        } switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37: 
            case 39: 
                dx = 0;
                break;

            case 38: 
            case 40: 
                dy = 0;
                break;
        }
} document.onkeydown = anim;
```

The #obstacle is a very simple fixed position rectangle:

```
#obstacle {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 200px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Although it's slightly complicated, you're usually better off having a model contain the locations of objects and the player. Do all the calcs on this model. Then have one function that turns all the objects in the model into html nodes you can render. The advantage is that you don't have to do pixel calculations to determine collisions, making the model calcs way easier. In it's most simplest form, have a 2D array representing a 'grid' with each index pair containing either nothing, an object, or the player. Then render everything into a table with each cell being a table cell.

Comment: That's probably a much better way of doing it, but honestly beyond my abilities at the moment. But I'll definitely start looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

My principle would be to store the position of the obstacle and on each anim(e) call, check if the new coordinates match the coordinates of the obstacle. From there on, you can create another function to handle the collision event or restrict the anim(e) movement.

I would implement functions like

```
function checkCollision(a, b)
function collision()
//and so on and so forth
```

See my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Snsa90/nejvmha3/) for more info.

For more complex situations you would need to do more math and more detailed checks with different methods. Hope this pushes you in the right direction.

This is my take on it coming from a web background, if you're interested in making actual games, try [canvas](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/) or better yet anything else than javascript.